# Binary streams parsing library for C

Tags: c, parsing

Could you advise a proven binary stream parsing library for C? It will be nice if it will be as declarative as C allows.

I need it for binary protocol parsing and describing the quite complicated protocol by it's formal specification, that's why I want it as much declarative as possible. Something like
Haskell's Data.Binary.Get will be great.

I've found binpac, but it seems heavyweight and oriented for C++ , but the project is pure C.

Example describing what I mean:

```
parser_t parsers[] = {
  { get_bit,      out_field1, &pkt.field1 }
 ,{ get_bit7,     0,           0          } // skip 7 bits
 ,{ get_word16be, out_field2, &pkt.field2 }
 ,{ 0,            0,           0          } // end
};

// skip
// char *data, char *data_end, 
map_parsers(data, data_end, parsers); // parse stream
```

UPD. It's fine to have just a fast library for sequential reading bits, words, aligned, unaligned, etc from memory. I may write declarative frontend or even DSL on my own.

Comment: C doesn't have a stream construct, perhaps if you gave us some example data, and where you get it from, ie FIFO, named pipe etc. then we could point you to a tool or library.

Comment: char* is good enough. example:

Comment: added example to the question

Comment: @Grady - "stream" is a common word irrespective of language or library support, and the point is usually to avoid the issue of whether the source is a file, a network connection or whatever and focus on the structure of the data.

Answer (score 7):

There's [PADS](http://www.padsproj.org/) from the nice people at AT&T. There's also [RAGEL](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) which can be used for the same thing. I've not used either myself, but found hints of their existence on [this page](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2496).

PADS looks like a similar idea to the ASN1 compiler from Objective Systems and Google Protocol buffers; you write a schema file, then compile that to the source code language of your choice. The difference of course is that those two work for strictly defined binary encoding schemes whereas PADS seemingly works for arbitrary data streams.

Good luck!

Comment: I use Ragel when I need to parse text data, but it's not very convenient for tasks like this. I'll try to play with PADS, thanks.

Comment: I've used Ragel and I mostly like it. It seems designed more for dealing with text files than binary but, of course, there's not much difference between an 8-bit character and an 8-bit byte. One thing - it's mostly regular-grammar based. There are some tricks where you can explicitly push info. to a stack etc, but it's at least theoretically possible to outgrow it's capabilities (e.g. needing a context-free grammar). In practice, though, I doubt that ever happens in binary files - in text files it just means you use Ragel for the tokenizer and have a parser layered on top.

Comment: Hi I noticed the PADs link is no longer active. Does anyone have a copy that could be made available or know where it is now being hosted?

Comment: @casillic, I think I've found it at https://github.com/yitzhakm/PADS-ML. There's a tgz which has the PADS C compiler inside.

Comment: @casillic, I've just succeeded in downloading PADS/C from http://www.padsproj.org/. Username and password are given at the bottom of their license agreement, and handed over my email and name to reach the download site from their homepage.